# android sqlite primitive type thet contains sqlite objects

Tags: android, sqlite

I saw this code

```
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();        
        values.put(CustomerOpenHelper.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, c.getFirstName());
        values.put(CustomerOpenHelper.COLUMN_LASTNAME, c.getLastName());
        values.put(CustomerOpenHelper.COLUMN_CITY, c.getCity());
        values.put(CustomerOpenHelper.COLUMN_WASTE, c.getWaste());       
        long insertId=database.insert(CustomerOpenHelper.TABLE_CUSTOMER, null, values);
         c.setCustormerId(insertId);        
        return c;
```

How can the primitive type "long insertId" contain this objects?

Answer (score 1):

It does not contain the object, it contains the object's ID, which is just a number that *identifies* the object. In other words, it's a unique number that can be used to look up the row in the table.